# URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute. URL: ./assets/i18n/en.json

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am new to Angular 2 and I have the following issue in the ngx-translate component (URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute. URL: ./assets/i18n/en.json). I am sure that this en.json file is there as I make http request to it and the request succeeds

Here is my app.module.server.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import {
    TranslateModule,
    TranslateLoader,
    MissingTranslationHandler,
    MissingTranslationHandlerParams
} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
    handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
        return '[' + params.key + ']';
    }
}

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [Http]
            }
        }),
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

---

and here is my app.module.cleint.ts  file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule,Http } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
import {
    TranslateModule,
    TranslateLoader,
    MissingTranslationHandler,
    MissingTranslationHandlerParams
} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
    handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
        return '[' + params.key + ']';
    }
}

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [Http]
            }
        }),
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
        {
            provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
            useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and here is my app.module.shared.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule, Http } from "@angular/http";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

import { TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { EmployeesListComponent } from './components/employees/EmployeesList.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        EmployeesListComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: 'employees-list', component: EmployeesListComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,TranslateModule
    ]
    , exports: [
        TranslateModule
    ]
};
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Well the issue is just this. ./assets/i18n/en.json is not an absolute url like :  http://foo.com/assets/i18n/en.json. I know that there are usually ways to indicate that you are serving from the same server as the client side code.  Might it not be

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

But when I poke around in the angular docs repos: I see this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15349. So maybe the angular http service doesn't support calling the host on which the document was served. That is sort of really surprising, but you can get that in javascript using:

```
window.location.origin
```

So just prepend that to /assets/i18n/ when you set up the call.

Comment: yes sir, the  file is there , when i make http request to the 
file(http://localhost:15199/assets/i18n/en.json), I got a response
and "createTranslateLoader" as per ngx-translate example on thier website

Comment: So you should be good if you change     return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json'); to     return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json'); Just drop the period in front of assets.

Comment: I tried this also, but did not work, and got the same error:
(URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute. URL: /assets/i18n/en.json)

Comment: @Mohammad did you find a solution for this?

Comment: he is saying put it directly, add isPlatformBrowser wrap, and call it a day.